# How to grab html_nodes for meta with itemprop equal to a certain value using rvest of tidyverse (Using R)

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest

```
library(stringr);
library(rvest); 

denzel = read_html("https://www.imdb.com/filmosearch/?explore=title_type&role=nm0000243&ref_=filmo_ref_typ&sort=num_votes,desc&mode=detail&page=1&title_type=movie");

titles = denzel %>%
            html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>%
            html_text();

titles;
```

The above code grabs a film list for Denzel Washington.  The HTML object works as expected.  I get the string-name titles for the 50 movies.

Specifically, I want to parse the following subelements in object.

```
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="7.8" />
<meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10" />
<meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="383446" />
```

In the above case, I want to extract the keys and values for each ... more specifically, I know the keys, so I would want to grab the associated values ...

```
meta = denzel %>%
    html_nodes("meta") %>%
    html_attr("itemprop");

meta;
```

This returns part of the content but not what I want.

The code below does not work, is psuedo code,

```
meta = denzel %>%
    html_nodes("meta") %>%
    html_attr("itemprop='ratingValue'");
```

Ideally meta (using html_node or html_nodes) would spit out the content attribute value by passing in the itemprop as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the data using `rvest` and then some data manipulation using `dplyr` could help to get it in right format.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(name = denzel %>% html_nodes("meta") %>% html_attr('itemprop'), 
           value = denzel %>% html_nodes("meta") %>% html_attr('content')) %>%
  filter(!is.na(name)) %>%
  mutate(movie_num = cumsum(name == 'ratingValue')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider() %>%
  mutate(title = titles) %>%
  select(movie_num, title, everything()) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

#   movie_num title             ratingValue bestRating ratingCount
#       <int> <chr>                   <dbl>      <int>       <int>
# 1         1 American Gangster         7.8         10      383451
# 2         2 Training Day              7.7         10      381124
# 3         3 Inside Man                7.6         10      331364
# 4         4 The Equalizer             7.2         10      325088
# 5         5 Man on Fire               7.7         10      323563
# 6         6 Flight                    7.3         10      319627
# 7         7 Deja Vu                   7           10      288497
# 8         8 The Book of Eli           6.9         10      288067
# 9         9 Philadelphia              7.7         10      219506
#10        10 Safe House                6.7         10      202055
# … with 40 more rows
```